# How to use rxjs progressOberserver

Tags: javascript, ajax, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I'm using rxjs to make an ajax request and would like to have an observable to show the progress. At [this docs page](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/blob/master/doc/operators/ajax.md) they describe a progressObserver but i cannot seem to get it to work:

```
const progress = Observable.create();

progress.subscribe(
  ev => console.log('progress', ev),
  err => console.error(err),
  () => console.log('done')
);

ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: `http://my-server-route`
  body: formData, // code for formData not included
  progressObserver: progress // this is where the magic should happen?!
}).subscribe(
  () => console.log('ajax done'),
  () => console.log('ajax error')
);
```

The console throws: cannot read property subscribe of undefined on the line with this code:

```
err => console.log(err)
```

I've tried some things with Subscriber but I'm not comfortable enough with rxjs to get this working.

Comment: RxJS-DOM is not compatible with RxJS 5.

Comment: @cartant could you show me an example with rxjs 4?

Comment: I've not used it; I'm just familiar with the breaking changes between RxJS 4 and 5.